# without using SDKs how can we scan fingerprint on mobile screen itself for validation of attendence?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using "Cordova" platform. I want to scan fingerprint and store in local storage and next time this finger print is taken for validation and attendance should be sent.

Comment: Although high level English is not expected here, following a minimal set of the [spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is gladly welcomed.

Answer (score -1):

There is a fingerprint auth plugin available for Android here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth

It seems pretty up to date.